# Generating a random hexadecimal number in Xquery

Tags: xquery, osb

i would like to have a random hexadecimal number generated for one of the field in the Xquery(which is used in OSB).

Previous mapping which we have,

```
<ns0:EmployeeID>{ data($EmployeeDetails/ns1:Employee/ns1:EmployeeID) }</ns0:EmployeeID>
```

Any help here?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think, i have figured it out
instead of the below

```
<ns0:EmployeeID>{ data($EmployeeDetails/ns1:Employee/ns1:EmployeeID) }</ns0:EmployeeID>
```

i have used like below and it worked

```
<ns0:EmployeeID>{fn-bea:uuid()}</ns0:EmployeeID>
```

Comment: How is a uuid a hexadecimal?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you shouldn't use uuid() because is just an activity's id representation, the best you could do it would be to write some java program using the require classes and invocated it through a java callout.